# Programmatically append to file in PHP

Tags: php, python, exec, file-permissions

I am trying to programmatically append an RSA public key to the authorized_keys file through a website and haven't been able to make any solutions I found work. I have tried using PHP's `file_put_contents()` function but I run into a permission denied error, and I have a python script that works, but I cannot seem to get PHP to execute it with either the `exec()` command or `shell_exec()`. Here's the relevant PHP code:

```
if(@$_POST['action']=='submit'){
    $key = $_POST['key_field'];

    //file_put_contents("/home/biosproject/.ssh/authorized_keys", $key, FILE_APPEND);

    $test = "/usr/bin/python savetofile.py \"".$key."\"";
    $tmp = shell_exec($test);
}
```

I'm aware that I need to sanitize the input but the site is currently in development so I'm just testing it like this in the meantime. Right now I'm using XAMPP which runs Apache. Is there something I'm missing or could try? For the PHP exec/shell_exec, I have tried using the full pathnames for all parts of the command, but nothing has worked yet. The python script is as follows:

```
#!usr/bin/python
import sys    
key = sys.argv[1]    
with open("/home/biosproject/.ssh/authorized_keys","a") as append:
    diditwork = append.write(key)
print key
```

As I mentioned before, this script is functional, but I can't call it from the PHP script.

### EDIT:

My authorized_keys file looks like so:
 -rw-rw-rw- 1 biosproject www-data 1200 Apr 15 13:17 /home/biosproject/.ssh/authorized_keys

### UPDATE:

I fixed the problem by bypassing permissions using a cron job that appends the necessary information from a database entry instead. Works great now!

Comment: inline `frite(fopen("filename.ext","a+"), "text" . PHP_EOL)`.

Comment: Permission still denied, unfortunately.

Comment: Apache/PHP needs the same permission user/group than authorized_keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python script won't help you here - it's a permissions issue with the `/home/biosproject/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, i.e. Apache doesn't have permission to modify it, and nor will any process it spawns, which would include your Python script.

Simplest fix would be to change the file permissions so it's writable by Apache. Assuming apache runs as group `www-data`, do...

```
sudo chgrp www-data /home/biosproject/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chmod g+w /home/biosproject/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

...although I forget if `ssh` complains if `authorized_keys` is set to `g+w`.

**Update**

It occurs to me that `www-data` will also need `+x` access to all parent directories of `/home/biosproject/.ssh/authorized_keys` to be able to change it, although I'm pretty sure that `ssh` will complain if you change the `.ssh` directory permissions in this way.

You'll either have to run apache with the same UID as the owner of the `/home/biosproject/.ssh` directory, or use a [`setuid`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) script to make the changes.

Comment: So far, I'm still getting the same thing. It failed to open the stream because permission was denied...

Comment: @JustAGuyIKnow Can you include the output from `ls -l /home/biosproject/.ssh/authorized_keys` in your question?

Comment: Sure, it should be up there now

Comment: @JustAGuyIKnow Should work. Maybe some strange PHP thing like [safe mode](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php), or something lower-level like [AppArmor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor) preventing it from being written to. If there's some location you **can** write to with PHP (say `/var/www`), perhaps you can put the file in `/var/www/authorized_keys`, and symlink it to `/home/biosproject/.ssh/authorized_keys`?

Comment: I'll have to try that when I get the chance. Will I still have to change the permissions if I go the symlink route?

Comment: @JustAGuyIKnow in theory, no, but ssh may still complain - I'm not sure. To be fair, though, allowing a webserver to modify an ssh keyfile gives the potential for a pretty large security hole.

Comment: I ended up using a cron job with root permissions to append to the file and now it works. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Explanation about my inline code:

```
$text = "nice text to append :P";
// open a file handler with a+ flag that means "open file for append and if it does not exist, create it"
$fo = fopen("filename.ext", "a+");
// append $text to file handler with a \n at the end
fwrite($fo, $text . PHP_EOL);
```

Comment: Your code makes functional sense, but I think the problem is with the file permissions, because it still doesn't like what I'm doing.